# isset strange behaviour and handling function returned data

Tags: php, isset

Could anyone please explain to me why the following line of code prints out true?

```
$a = "string";

if(isset($a['error'])) echo true; else echo false;
```

When I do a function call, I return the expected data if it worked properly, or return `array("error" => $error)`;

Then on receiving the returned data I check if isset($var['error']) and if its not then I know I received some expected data.

I would also appreciate if you could advice me if this a good or bad way of handling data between function calls? And if there is a better "good practice" for this.

Comment: Used Exceptions in case of exceptional situations. You shouldn't misuse return values for state information. Also note, that your approach will behave differently with 5.4. http://codepad.viper-7.com/11HMOS

Comment: [Wello!](http://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/11xn3a/guess_the_value_of_foo/)

Comment: Why did my question get a -1? Was it not a good enough question for the experts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is some of PHP misbehaviors, which luckily has been fixed in some recent version.

You can address a single character in a string using the same square braces used to address an array element.

`'error'` evaluates to 0 and then you have got `$a[0]` which is set.

to fix that you have to check if $a is array first

Comment: it's a bug, as magic happens if you use `$a = str_split("string)";` :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug and it's fixed in PHP 5.4+: http://codepad.viper-7.com/fz1rnT

looks like `isset($str[$key])` in same way as `isset($str[intval($key)])`, where `$str` and `$key` are strings

To handle errors best approach are exceptions:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why the behavior is like this, but I do know that PHP allows you to handle strings in a similar way as an array.

```
$a = "StackOverflow";

echo $a[2]; // a
echo $a[4]; // k
echo $a[6]; // v
echo $a[8]; // r
```

Now when you pass a string key as an index of the array, PHP will try to parse that string into a numerical value to use as a key.

```
echo $a['stack']; // S
echo $a['over']; // S
echo $a['flow']; // S

echo $a['0stack']; // S
echo $a['1over']; // t
echo $a['2flow']; // a
echo $a['3flow']; // c
echo $a['4flow']; // k
```

Comment: @melpomene yeah as `intval('5abcde');` is `5`

Comment: @mel -true true true... Thanks for that - I've made some edits.